# CUDA Median filter not working properly

Tags: image, filter, cuda, median

I took it upon myself to learn CUDA, and tried to implement a simple median filter for image processing. This is what I came up with, but I can't seem to get any good results with the images that come out of it. For instance, the output picture is relatively noise free, but the saturation of the picture seems higher, and when I tried this picture of a [teddy bear](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Median_filter_example.jpg) from Wikipedia, his nose gets green for some reason. I became too frustrated to think of any new ideas, so if anyone can see the problem in the code, I would be most gratefull. Thanks!

This is the kernel function:

```
__global__ void median_filter(int *input, int *output, int IMAGE_W, int IMAGE_H){

    __shared__ float window[BLOCK_W*BLOCK_H][9];

    int x, y, tid;
    int i, j, iMin, temp;

    x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    tid = threadIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.x;

    if(x>=IMAGE_W && y>=IMAGE_H)
        return;

    /* setting 3x3 window elements for median */
    if(y==0 && x==0)
        window[tid][0] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y==0 && x!=0)
        window[tid][0] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x-1];
    else if(y!=0 && x==0)
        window[tid][0] = input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x];
    else
        window[tid][0] = input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x-1];

    window[tid][1] = (y==0)?input[y*IMAGE_W+x]:input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x];

    if(y==0 && x==IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][2] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y!=0 && x==IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][2] = input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y==0 && x!=IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][2] = input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x+1];
    else
        window[tid][2] = input[(y-1)*IMAGE_W+x+1];

    window[tid][3] = (x==0)?input[y*IMAGE_W+x]:input[y*IMAGE_W+x-1];
    window[tid][4] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x];
    window[tid][5] = (x==IMAGE_W-1)?input[y*IMAGE_W+x]:input[y*IMAGE_W+x+1];

    if(y==IMAGE_H-1 && x==0)
        window[tid][6] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y!=IMAGE_H-1 && x==0)
        window[tid][6] = input[(y+1)*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y==IMAGE_H-1 && x!=0)
        window[tid][6] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x-1];
    else
        window[tid][6] = input[(y+1)*IMAGE_W+x-1];

    window[tid][7] = (y==IMAGE_H-1)?input[y*IMAGE_W+x]:input[(y+1)*IMAGE_W+x];

    if(y==IMAGE_H-1 && x==IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][8] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y!=IMAGE_H-1 && x==IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][8] = input[(y+1)*IMAGE_W+x];
    else if(y==IMAGE_H-1 && x!=IMAGE_W-1)
        window[tid][8] = input[y*IMAGE_W+x+1];
    else
        window[tid][8] = input[(y+1)*IMAGE_W+x+1];

    __syncthreads();

    /* sorting window to find median */
    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
        iMin = j;
        for(i=j+1; i<9; i++){
            if(window[tid][i] < window[tid][iMin]){
                iMin = i;
            }
        }
        if(iMin != j){
            temp = window[tid][iMin];
            window[tid][iMin] = window[tid][j];
            window[tid][j] = temp;
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    output[y*IMAGE_W + x] = window[tid][4];
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main(){
    /*loading picture*/
    char picture[50] = "before.bmp";

    FILE *image = fopen(picture, "rb");

    if(image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Load picture error!\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpIHeader;
    fread(&bmpFHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, image);
    fread(&bmpIHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, image);

    int imgWidth = bmpIHeader.biWidth;
    int imgHeight = bmpIHeader.biHeight;

    int img_size = imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(int);

    int * imgeRedChannel_x = (int *)malloc(img_size);
    int * imgeGreenChannel_x = (int *)malloc(img_size);
    int * imgeBlueChannel_x = (int *)malloc(img_size);

    int * deviceInputRed;
    int * deviceInputGreen;
    int * deviceInputBlue;

    int * deviceOutputRd;
    int * deviceOutputGreen;
    int * deviceOutputBlue;

    for(int i = imgHeight-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<imgWidth; j++)
        {

                fread(&(imgeGreenChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j]), sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);
                fread(&(imgeBlueChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j]), sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);
                fread(&(imgeRedChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j]), sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);

        }
    }

    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceInputRed, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceInputBlue, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceInputGreen, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceOutputRd, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceOutputBlue, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &deviceOutputGreen, sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth);

    int dimA = imgWidth*imgHeight;
    int numThreadsPerBlock = 256;
    int numBlocks = dimA / numThreadsPerBlock;
    int sharedMemSize = numThreadsPerBlock*sizeof(int);

    dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
    dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);

    cudaMemcpy(deviceInputRed,imgeRedChannel_x,sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy h-d r");
    cudaMemcpy(deviceInputGreen,imgeGreenChannel_x,sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy h-d g");
    cudaMemcpy(deviceInputBlue,imgeBlueChannel_x,sizeof(int) * imgHeight * imgWidth,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy h-d b");

    median_filter<<< dimGrid , dimBlock, sharedMemSize>>> (deviceInputRed, deviceOutputRd, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    checkCUDAError("kernel invocation r");
    median_filter<<< dimGrid , dimBlock, sharedMemSize>>> (deviceInputGreen, deviceOutputGreen, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    checkCUDAError("kernel invocation g");
    median_filter<<< dimGrid , dimBlock, sharedMemSize>>> (deviceInputBlue, deviceOutputBlue, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    checkCUDAError("kernel invocation b");

    cudaMemcpy(imgeRedChannel_x, deviceOutputRd, imgHeight * imgWidth * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy d-h r");
    cudaMemcpy(imgeGreenChannel_x, deviceOutputGreen, imgHeight * imgWidth * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy d-h g");
    cudaMemcpy(imgeBlueChannel_x, deviceOutputBlue, imgHeight * imgWidth * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    checkCUDAError("memcpy d-h b");

    cudaFree(deviceInputRed);
    cudaFree(deviceOutputRd);
    cudaFree(deviceInputGreen);
    cudaFree(deviceOutputGreen);
    cudaFree(deviceInputBlue);
    cudaFree(deviceOutputBlue);

    /*saving new picture*/
    fclose(image);

    char title[50]="after";
    strcat(title, ".bmp");

    remove(title);
    image = fopen(title,"wb");

    fwrite(&bmpFHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, image);
    fwrite(&bmpIHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, image);

    for(int i = imgHeight-1; i>=0; i--)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j<imgWidth; j++)
        {
            int b = imgeBlueChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j];
            int g = imgeGreenChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j];
            int r = imgeRedChannel_x[i * (imgWidth) + j]; 

            if(b>255)b=255;
            if(g>255)g=255;
            if(r>255)r=255;



            fwrite(&g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);
            fwrite(&b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);
            fwrite(&r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, image);
        }
    }

    printf("Success!\n");
    fclose(image);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "can't seem to get any good results" mean? Please describe the problem in a bit more detail in your question

Comment: @talonmies The output picture is relatively noise free, but the saturation of the picture seems higher, and when I tried this picture of a [teddy bear](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Median_filter_example.jpg) from Wikipedia, his nose gets green for some reason.

Comment: Why not include your *whole* program if you're going to include this much code anyway?  For example, nowhere have you told us what `BLOCK_W` and `BLOCK_H` represent.  But in any event I'm pretty sure that all your lines that reference `window[tid][]` in some fashion will not work.  You should run this code through cuda-memcheck and I think you will see a bunch of shared memory access errors.  Furthermore, I think this line of code: `if(x>=IMAGE_W && y>=IMAGE_H)` should be this: `if(x>=IMAGE_W || y>=IMAGE_H)`

Comment: @musasabi... why are you passing 3rd parameter of kernel configuration, if there is no dynamic shared memory in your kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The nose getting green means you have overflows in your code, but that's strange because a median filter should never generate overflows. You surely have a messed up code there, the kernel doesn't make much sense especially the lots of extra work you're doing.

In non linear filters I suggest you try implementing Min or Max filters first to see if they work. Here's a working code for Max Filter from [CUVI](http://cuvilib.com/) Library for CUDA. Your Median kernel should be no different than this:

```
__global__ void median_8u_c3( unsigned char* out,
                              unsigned int width,
                              unsigned int widthStep,
                              unsigned int height){

int xIndex = blockIdx.x*BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
int  yIndex = blockIdx.y*BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;
int tid = yIndex * widthStep + (3*xIndex);

if(xIndex>=width|| yIndex>=height) return;

int limitX = anchorX + fHeight - 1;
int limitY = anchorY + fWidth - 1;

unsigned char MAX_R = 0 , MAX_G = 0, MAX_B = 0;  


 // Instead of Max filter code in the for loops below, you can have median code
for(Cuvi32s i=anchorX ; i<= limitX; i++)
    for(Cuvi32s j=anchorY ; j<= limitY; j++)
    {
        MAX_R = (tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)  , yIndex + j) > MAX_R) ? tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)  , yIndex + j) : MAX_R;
        MAX_G = (tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)+1, yIndex + j) > MAX_G) ? tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)+1, yIndex + j) : MAX_G;
        MAX_B = (tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)+2, yIndex + j) > MAX_B) ? tex2D(tex8,3*(xIndex + i)+2, yIndex + j) : MAX_B;
    }


out[tid] = MAX_R;
out[tid + 1] = MAX_G;
out[tid + 2] = MAX_B;
}
```

Note: I'm using input from Textures.

Comment: Is cuvi library open source? And what is `Cuvi32s`?

Comment: No, it's not open source. Cuvis32s is 'int'